# Does Windows 8 Support 16-bit Programs?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, 16-bit

With Vista and up, 64-bit versions of Windows no longer support 16-bit programs, but 32-bit versions can still run them. Windows 8 has changed a lot of things from even Windows 7, and there were rumors a while back that it would *only* be available in 64-bit<sup>[[1]](http://www.w7forums.com/windows-8-wont-support-32bit-t3602.html)[[2]](http://www.win8forums.com/threads/windows-8-only-64-bit.248)</sup> which seems [not to be the case anymore](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/iso). It’s no secret thet Microsoft is pushing users to migrate to 64-bit systems. Have they dropped 16-bit support from Windows 8 altogether (including 32-bit versions)?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @NathanAdams, your question makes no sense. Why would someone want to jump out of a plane or move to another country? Just because *you* have no need doesn’t mean that nobody else in the whole world does (hence the continuing 16-bit support in Windows 8). If you are simply asking of a practical reason, then the answer is *because some people have 16-bit programs that have/want to run*.

Comment: The point is that most 16bit programs that attempt to run on a modern processor may not run (right) at all due to the vast difference in clock speed. This is apparent in many games. You wouldn't want your book keeping application as a 16bit application. With the advent of services available via the cloud, software available for pennies on the dollar, and subcontracting for super cheap - it doesn't make sense to run such archaic software.

Comment: @NathanAdams, again, you are simplifying things for yourself. There do exist tools that may run just fine. For example, I have some simple command-line tools that are 16-bit like old `.com` files or programs compiled with Pascal for DOS that do things like `echo` without a newline, move the cursor, set text colors, print the date/time, parse a file, etc. These work just fine and while some functions may now be built-in, many/most are not and it is not always feasible (or even possible in some cases) to update and/or re-compile them for 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: We actually use (modern) software that requires a dongle.  The dongle requires a driver that is 16bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While 64-bit copies of Windows 8 do not support 16-bit applications, they *are* still supported on 32-bit copies<sup>[[1]](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-windows-8-32-bit-can-still-run-16-bit-apps)[[2]](http://www.askvg.com/windows-8-comes-with-built-in-16-bit-application-support)[[3]](http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-8-will-run-16-bit-apps-says-microsoft)</sup>. However, they are not supported by default and must be manually turned on with a Control Panel applet:

[image: 16-bit support Control Panel applet]

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as Windows Vista or Windows 7.
If you have a 64bit version of Windows, you cannot run 16bit applications.
If you have a 32bit version of Windows, you can run 16bit applications.

Workaround for 64bit systems:
In Windows 7 64bit you could just download the Virtual PC XP Mode and run your 16bit application there.
I'm not sure if Windows 8 also provides an XP Mode (I don't think so) but (some versions?) of Windows 8 come with Hyper-V support. So you could easily run e.g. Windows XP in your Hyper-v to have 16bit support.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8)

Comment: Yup, there’s [already plenty of that](http://superuser.com/search?q=64-bit+16-bit). I guess people *are* still using 16-bit programs. ☺

Answer (score 0):

As per Windows 7, 16-bit applications simply cannot run on a 64-bit Windows 8 installation.

However, the [NTVDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_DOS_machine#NTVDM) required to run 16-bit applications is still available on 32-bit Windows 8 systems:

> The NTVDM is present in all 32-bit NT-based Windows versions including Vista, 7 and 8, except for in 64-bit versions.

As Synetech noted, this feature is disable by default and must be manually enabled.